# Why my recent upvotes haven't changed my reputation?

Tags: support, community-wiki

It is not that I loose sleep because of this, but I am curious. I posted an answer and it collected 4 upvotes yesterday, but my reputation hasn't changed. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Presumably you are discussing [your answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/46210/520) to [*How much of the universe is observable at visible wavelengths?*](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/46189/520).

What has happened is that [you edited it so many times that it was automatically converted to a "community wiki" post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts). Note the different format of the user-card at the bottom right of the post:[image: user card example]

The purpose of the automatic conversion feature is to (1) prevent the original poster for benefiting from a post that has been extensively edited by others and to discourage frivolous edits.

I'm going to de-wiki this one for you, but this is not something that you should count on happening again in the future. It is generally recommended that you work on your posts offline so that you will only make a few edits.

Comment: Thanks! Most of the edits are due to grammar corrections, or simple attempts to make the text easier to read, but I guess this time they were too many...