# Would it be a problem if I wikify all my answers?

Tags: support, community-wiki

I was about to report a bug when I noticed [why my recent upvotes haven't changed my reputation](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2765/why-my-recent-upvotes-havent-changed-my-reputation). I heavily edit my answers as I am trying to develop technical writing skills, upvotes with low reputation would be a better figure of merit.

Would wikifying most of my answers cause problems? 
If so at what number of edits does a post wikify?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Would wikifying most of my answers cause problems?

Technically no; it doesn't *directly* cause any problem with the functionality of the site. But reputation is a measure of how much the community trusts you, and to that end it's useful to other people as well as yourself. So it is better for the community if you *don't* intentionally wikify your posts. And it doesn't give you any benefit to do so.

Also, community wiki mode is a signal that edits from others are especially welcome; it's meant for the few posts that are really supposed to be collectively written by multiple people. Normal questions and answers don't fit that qualification.

That being said, if you want to go ahead and wikify your posts, it's not something you would get in trouble for (i.e. we wouldn't suspend someone just for that, unless it causes some sort of serious problem in a way we haven't foreseen). But also bear in mind that we will not go through and reverse wiki mode on a large number of posts if you change your mind later. If you decide to make a post community wiki, it will be stuck that way.

Comment: Excellent, I wont be wanting the wiki mode reversed. If I wiki mode at a point where I think I have done a good job, it would be informative to see what changes are made if anyone should bother.

Comment: I agree that reputation is a measure of community trust, but but a member reading a question without the expertise to assess answers will vote for the highest rep in attempt to participate. The answers I have given so far lead me to this conclusion.

Comment: That _could_ happen, but you can't argue that it _does_ happen simply because you've noticed that answers by people with more reputation get more upvotes. It could be that people with more reputation have it because they write better answers (and have been on the site longer).

Comment: I don't want to call people out but give a specific example [here](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/106475/is-kerr-effect-in-glass-observable/106514#106514) My vote went to Parth, John got two votes early and misinterprets the question. I picked up one only recently. I'd suggest it *did* happen. I often misinterpret question myself this is not an accusation, nor am I saying the system sucks it's "democratic". I just want to minimise that type of vote for me. At this point in time the ill-informed votes are at %50.

Answer (score 6):

As to when a post automatically becomes community wiki the rules are set out here:

[Create Wiki Posts](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/community-wiki)

> There are also several ways a question or answer can automatically enter community wiki mode. In these cases, we believe that the post is de-facto wiki:
>
> - the body of the post has been edited by at least **5** different users
> - the post has been edited **10** times by the original owner
> - you answer a question marked community wiki
> - a question generates more than **30** answers

So in your case I'd try to make each edit more significant to reduce the total number of edits. If you spot a spelling mistake or think you can express something better then take a bit more time to review the whole post so you don't have to repeat the process later.

Comment: Thanks, I agree I could be more organised. Is my question clear? I want to wikify most of my posts so I can limit my reputation. Clearly I have not read all the site info yet, perhaps the wiki has a more specific purpose.

Comment: Ok now I have read the link you posted, question answered

Comment: @baldrik - Ah. I missed that aspect. However, I'd still advocate making fewer, more significant edits.

Comment: @baldrik: why would you want to limit your reputation? A high reputation allows you to assist with the running of the site and improve it for everyone.

Comment: @john Yes I understand that. Selfishly, I don't have time for that right now. I am not good at organising concepts and thoughts on a page in a way that targets the audience appropriately. I need to practice writing, doing that here is the only way I can contribute right now. I believe I will get a more reliable measure of progress in achieving my aims if reputation is not a factor, this position may change. I do do need the comment everywhere privilege but the others can wait.

Comment: @baldrik You don't *have* to take part in other activities just because you have the necessary reputation to do it, although it is appreciated if you do.

Comment: @baldrik limiting your reputation doesn't allow you to do anything more than you could if you had a high reputation, so it seems pretty pointless to wikify everything for that purpose.

Comment: @david Hehe Ok let me try again.

Comment: @david My goal is to be a better writer. How do I do that? Practice writing. It would nice to have some measure of whether I am moving toward that goal. Which means I need someone to read it. PhysicsSE is the appropriate audience with many levels of understanding. From my short time here I feel that the best figure of merit is upvotes with a low rep the only way I know how to achieve that measurement is to use the wiki state of a page. If the community feels that is inappropriate I wont do it. It does not appear to against the guidelines posted in the answer.

Comment: The fact that I am having this discussion has made me literally LOL. Because it is an example of my inability to communicate in text. It maybe that the figure of merit is bogus in which case my position will change.

Comment: @baldrik (2 comments up) I'm not sure what you're saying here. What do you want to use the wiki state of a page to achieve? You do know that upvotes are uncorrelated with wiki mode, right? (i.e. the system doesn't separately track upvotes given before and after a post is wikified)

Comment: @david I don't see that as a problem I don't need the system to differentiate those votes.

Comment: OK, but then what is the point of wikifying your answers? I don't understand what you've said about that.

Comment: I don't want reputation to influence whether my target audience, non-experts, upvote my answer. I am now thinking I should have just gone ahead and wikfied my answers, and plead ignorance if I popped up on any radar. All I can say is my motivation is not sinister, wikifying does not seem to cause any technical problems and as you say does not give me any advantage, so why should my motivation matter?